# iOS: ScrollView with clickable objects inside

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

The following lines of code represents objects that i insert into a scrollView.

My problem is, none of the images inside the scrollview are drag-and-droppable.

When the images are added alone, that is outside the scrollview, they are perfectly click - and drag-and-droppable.

It appears every event that occur triggers the scrollViews listener, and not the clicked image listener.

The scrollView is perfectly scrollable regardless of how the images are added.

**How can i trigger the image drag-and-drop if clicked, and still be able to scroll it's parent view - the scrollView?**

```
#import "BookShelfSection.h"

@implementation BookShelfSection



- (id)initBookShelfWithX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return self;
}

    - (void)addPages:(NSArray *)fileNameArray
{
    for (id shelf in fileNameArray) {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithString:shelf]];
        UIImageView *page = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        page.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        page.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;

        UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car_1.png"];
        Item *item = [[Item alloc] initWithImage:image2 andPosition:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
        page.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        item.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [view addSubview:page];
        [view addSubview:item];

        [self addPageView:view];
    }

}


@end
```

**EDIT: This is how i perform my drag and drop:
The Item Class:**

```
#import "Item.h"

@implementation Item

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image andPosition:(CGPoint)position
{

    CGRect cellRectangle = CGRectMake(position.x, position.y,image.size.width ,image.size.height );

    self = [[Item alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle];
    if (self) {
        [self setImage:image];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
}
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
    frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
    [self setFrame:frame];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    int originX = (int)roundf(frame.origin.x);
    int originY = (int)roundf(frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"Touch ended at point: [%d, %d]", originX, originY);


}

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch cancelled");
}

@end
```

Comment: put scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES; and for images also

Comment: edited, no luck yet. Thanks

Comment: How do you perform the drag and drop?

Comment: Edited, see the Item class, Thanks.

Comment: I edited the way i create item.

Answer (score 0):

Add that to the UIImageView:

```
page.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
item.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Edited: Still no progress though.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears every event that occur triggers the scrollViews listener, and not the clicked image listener.

When you catch this event for scrollview, loop through your added page/images & check the value of userInteractionEnabled ? May be that will help to narrow down the problem.